# Is it possible to use shrine 3.0 in rails 4.2? so that we could replace paperclip immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

We have our site  running successfully for the past 10 years. It is a rails based app. During the process we upgraded rails to 4.2 version. Further up gradation to rails 5 would require effort.

The main issue is we are using paper clip which has reached the end of life. We would like to use at least shrine 3.0  and replace paper clip. I have seen the dependency of rack 2.0 we are using rack less then 2.0 . My main question is will your toolkit shrine 3.0 support working on rails 4.2. Also we have shrine lambda plugin which is supporting 2.6 versions. This is using old version and back grounding plugin.

```
Our use case 
    - Use shrine > = 3.0
    - Use direct multipart s3 upload
    - Some plugin to use the lambda on aws
```

Our progress

```
  - We have tweaked your demo app (with uppy direct multipart upload) in rails 6.0 to work in rails 5.0
  - We have created a thumbnail creator in node.js in 8 runtime.
  - We have hosted this lambda function in aws this responds to bucket events. This is probably a crude method as it just catches bucket event and creates thumbnail.
    There is no connection with the upload app. Initially intended to use the shrine lambda plugin but this plugin (https://github.com/texpert/shrine-lambda) is for older version of shrine. If this plugin could be upgraded to wok with shrine 3.0 then this would be great.
    work with the shrine 3.0
```

Our main query
     - Is it possible to use shrine 3.0 in rails 4.2? so that we could replace paperclip immediately
     - A combination of uppy multipart direct upload to use AWS lambda function. 
           The benefits are
               - Offload the image upload from the server.
               - Offload creating of thumbnails to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Shrine 3.2.1 in a Rails 4.2.11.1 app with rack 1.6.13. Seems to work fine.